# define Map with T[K]

Tags: typescript, es6-map, keyof

I'm currently in the process of transitioning from JS to TS and can't quite get my head around `keyof`. I found https://github.com/kimamula/TypeScript-definition-of-EventEmitter-with-keyof and now I'm trying to implement this. All went fine until I turned on 'noImplicitAny'.

I have made an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20EventEmitter%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20events%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20((arg%3A%20keyof%20T)%20%3D%3E%20any)%5B%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.events%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20((arg%3A%20keyof%20T)%20%3D%3E%20any)%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getOrCreateEvents%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(event%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(arg%3A%20T%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20((arg%3A%20T%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any)%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.events.get(event)%20%7C%7C%20this.events.set(event%2C%20new%20Array%3C(arg%3A%20T%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E()).get(event)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D) in the ts playground to show the issue I'm having:

In the constructor there's no access to `K` so I had to explicitly make the Map `(arg: any)` to get it to work.

Is there a solution that avoids using any when creating the Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign  `(arg: keyof T) => any` to `(arg: T[K]) => any`. `keyof T` represents any property name of `T` For example in this class:

```
class X { test: string; test2: number; }
```

`keyof X` is the same as `'test' | 'test2'`
while `T[K]` with `K extends keyof T` represents the type of the property of `T` with the name `K`, so for the class above `T[K]` can be either `number` or `string` depending on the value passed for `K`

So if you have `Emitter<X>` you would basically trying to assign `(arg: string | number) => any` to `(arg: 'test' | 'test2') => any` which is definitely not type safe.

My guess is that you want to constrain `listener` to have an argument with the same property type as a member of the class. For that you should use `Map<string, ((arg: T[keyof T]) => any) []>` to have `arg` constrained to any possible property type of `T`

```
class EventEmitter<T> {

  private events: Map<string, ((arg: T[keyof T]) => any) []>;

  constructor() {
    this.events = new Map<string, ((arg: T[keyof T]) => any) []>();
  }

  public getOrCreateEvents<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: (arg: T[K]) => any): ((arg: T[K]) => any) [] {

    return this.events.get(event) || this.events.set(event, new Array<(arg: T[K]) => any>()).get(event);
  }
}

// Test 
class X { test: string; test2: number; }
var d = new EventEmitter<X>();
d.getOrCreateEvents("test2", c => console.log(c));// c is infered to string
d.getOrCreateEvents("test2", c => console.log(c)); // c is infered to number
```